# MYSQL How can I get the data for last 1 month when the time stamp is store in unixtime stamp

Tags: mysql

How can I get the data for 1 month when the time stamp is store in unixtime stamp

Have a DB storing the timestamp as unix time stamp , how to get all data from a specific time to one month back in mySQL?

Table:table

| Name | phone | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123456 | 1686589382 |
| def | 232323 | 1686589386 |
| efg | 343434 | 1689219182 |

E.g

if time = 1689219182

I want to get all the data for past one month till the specific date (1689219182)

My query should return me:

| Name | phone | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123456 | 1686589382 |
| def | 232323 | 1686589386 |

I tried using this command but it is giving me error:

```
select * from table where time < unix_timestamp((from_unixtime(1689219182)) - interval 1 month);
```

DB::Exception: Number of arguments for function formatDateTime doesn't match: passed 1, should be 2 or 3

**Likewise I also want to get the data for past 1 week interval**

Comment: The error message you've posted doesn't come from that query, or from MySQL, so there's clearly something missing.

Comment: I think it is the framework I am using which is causing the issue. Is there a way to get the data for past 1 week in any other way (another and better SQL query) ?

Comment: *How can I get the data for last 1 month* ```WHERE `time` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)```

Comment: @Akina I want the data for last 1 month from a specific time.
e.g get the data for past 1 month interval from the time = 1689219182

i.e all the data between time range 1686589382 and 1689219182

Comment: @Byte If there's a framework that causing an error, don't you think it appropriate to include that information in your question, and the code involved? You're asking us to diagnose a problem in code we can't see.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I do undestand your point. I am just looking for alternatives of this query which might run on my case

Comment: *i.e all the data between time range 1686589382 and 1689219182* In this case use simple ```WHERE `time` BETWEEN 1686589382 AND 1689219182```

Comment: The Clickhouse DB we are using is an old version and does not support the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function correctly. There is nothing I can do instead calculate the time in code and then pass the calculated previous month/week time in the query

Answer (score 0):

Use `BETWEEN` to get the rows between two times. `<` will get all the rows before a specific time.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE time BETWEEN unix_timestamp((from_unixtime(1689219182)) - interval 1 month) AND 1689219182
```

Replace `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` with `INTERVAL 1 WEEK` to make it the week before the given timestamp.